# Unrecognized selector sent to instance - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

This question has been asked a few times on SO, but the solution always seems to be adding `:` to the end of the `action` String, or adding a sender parameter, like `UIButton` or `AnyObject`, but this does not apply to me.

Here is my code: (inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function)

```
    let mapsbut = cell.viewWithTag(912) as! UIButton

    mapsbut.addTarget(self, action: "mapsHit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    func mapsHit(sender: UIButton!){

        passBuild = buildings[indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mapSegue2", sender: self)

    }
    return cell
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `mapsHit` function out of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function to make it a global (in the view controller context) instead of a nested function within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: This may work, but I need to use a value from the cell in the function, so that approach won't suit me.